# Storing a text file into SQLite3 database using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have done some operations with a file using python. Now all i have to is to create one table with two columns...one is for msgid and another is for msgstr...all `msgid`s should be stored in `msgid` column and all `msgstr`s should be stored in `msgstr` column..

I am very new to the programming world. Kindly help me. I have pasted what i had done below:

```
fn='ru.po'
f=open(fn)
output=[]
for line in f:
    if not '#' in line:
        output.append(line)
f.close()
f=open(fn,'w')
f.writelines(output)
f.close
```

Comment: I think this is probably too broad of a question for stackoverflow.  Please review a python sqlite tutorial (for example http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/) and ask any specific questions you may have.

Comment: You want to store the whole file in the DB or save a link/path to it?

Comment: Your `.po` file has no inherent structure, and it also includes blank lines and meta data. I could guess that you want to store `msgid` and `msgstr` as columns in a table of the database, but you need to make clearer your requirements.

Comment: I want to store the whole file in the DB

Comment: @mhawke.... you got my point.... plz help me

Comment: The whole file. OK. Can't see any point in that, but do you want each line from the file stored in a single column, one per row in the table, or do you want the entire contents of the file in one column in one row?

Comment: @kmg1: now you are just confusing me. Please update the question to clarify the requirements. Specify the schema for a start.

Comment: I want two columns...one is for msgid and one is for msgstr

Comment: @mhawke: is it all right now?

Comment: @kmg1: your update to the question conflicts with your comments. In the question you say 2 tables,  in the comments you say 1 table with 2 columns. Anyway, there are plenty of SQLite tutorials about the place, I suggest looking over some of those.

Comment: @mhawke: question updated..sorry for my fault...

Comment: @mhawke  will u answer to my question plz?

Comment: @kmg1 : answer is waiting for you.

Comment: @mhawke THNX A LOT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this:

1. Extracting the `msgid` and corresponding `msgstr` values from the
   .po file.
2. Inserting the `msgid` and `msgstr` into a table in the SQLite
   database.

For part 1, I suggest using the [`babel`](http://babel.pocoo.org/) module. You can install it with

```
pip install babel
```

Use the `babel.messages.pofile.read_po()` function to read the `.po` file. This will return a catalog on which you can iterate over all of the messages parsed from the file:

```
from babel.messages.pofile import read_po

with open('ru.po') as po_file:
    cat = read_po(po_file)

for message in cat:
    if message.id:
        print '{!r} -> {!r}'.format(message.id, message.string)
```

---

For part 2:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('catalog.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
result = cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE ru (msgid TEXT, msgstr TEXT)')

# bulk insert the messages
messages = [(msg.id, msg.string) for msg in cat if msg.id]
result = cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO ru (msgid, msgstr) VALUES (?, ?)',  messages)
assert(result.rowcount == len(messages))
conn.commit()

result = cursor.execute("SELECT * from ru where msgid = '11 inches/sec.'")
msgid, msgstr = result.fetchone()
# .encode('utf8') can be removed for Python 3
print '"{}" translates to "{}"'.format(msgid, msgstr.encode('utf8'))

msgid = 'A Samba password is required to export printer drivers'
result = cursor.execute("SELECT * from ru where msgid = ?", (msgid,))
msgid, msgstr = result.fetchone()
print '"{}" translates to "{}"'.format(msgid, msgstr.encode('utf8'))
```

**Output**

```
"11 inches/sec." translates to "11 дюймов/с"
"A Samba password is required to export printer drivers" translates to "Для экспорта драйверов принтера требуется пароль Samba"
```

You might notice that there are lot of `msgid`s with empty `msgstr`s. If you don't want them, then modify

```
messages = [(msg.id, msg.string) for msg in cat if msg.id]
```

to

```
messages = [(msg.id, msg.string) for msg in cat if msg.id and msg.string]
```